# Swift Category in Objective-C Framework not recognised at run time

Tags: objective-c, swift, categories

I did create a NSString category in Objective-C (function "substringFromString:toString:"). It's part of my own framework, that I use in my apps. The Objective-C framework's components use this function as well as my new Swift app. The framework has been used so many times and works fine. I have added the framework to my Swift project and added the NSString category to the bridging header file. The app compiles fine, but as soon as the category is used by one of my components within the library I get the following error:

```
-[Swift._NSContiguousString substringFromString:toString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe6a8d2d550
```

As mentioned it's one of my Objective-C components in the Objective-C library, that throws this exception. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: May be because `NSString` in Objective-C and `String` in Swift are different things. Try use `NSString` instead `String`.

Answer (score 5):

Just got it. I had to add "-ObjC" as a linker flag.